# Restrict table data value to 4 digits

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a simple calculator using HTML, CSS and Vanilla Javascript. Where I want to make sure that the input field (display screen) does not have more than 4 digits in the first operand and similarly for the next operands to follow.

*Story so far*
**index.html**

```
<table class="calculator">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><input class="display-box" type="text" id="result" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="button" type="button" value="1" onclick="display('1')" /> </td>
        <td><input class="button" type="button" value="2" onclick="display('2')" /> </td>
        <td><input class="button" type="button" value="3" onclick="display('3')" /> </td>
        <td><input class="button" type="button" value="*" onclick="display('*')" /></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

**script.js**

```
function display(value) {
    document.getElementById("result").value += value;
    // var ops = ["+", "-", "%", "*", "/"];
    result=document.getElementById("result").value
    result=result.split(/[+-/*]+/).pop();
    console.log(result)
    if(result>9999){
        document.getElementById("result").value = "Error"
        alert("Error: Entered more than 4 digits")
    }
}
```

This works for 1st set of operand, and then `var result` takes 4 digits + next operand(of length 1) i.e. next entered number which makes its length 5 and alert pops up. Ideally, result should be set to null on encountering any operator and then take the length of the next operand and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q99qe.png)Here, I use temp variable which store value of digit entered after a operator. initially the "value" give a digit in string type so, i convert it in number type and append this number in temp variable. when user click on the operator then temp value become 0, then this process continue until temp>9999 is satisfy and then an error msg is shown to user.

```
    temp = 0;
    function display(value) {
        var k = parseInt(value);
        console.log(k);
        temp = temp*10 + k; 
    document.getElementById("result").value += value;
    var ops = ["+", "-", "%", "*", "/"];
    
    result=document.getElementById("result").value
    if(ops.includes(value)){
        temp=0
        console.log("Ops found!")
        flag = true;
    }
    console.log(temp)
    console.log(result)
    if(temp>9999){
        document.getElementById("result").value = "Error"
        
        alert("Error: Entered more than 4 digits")
    }
```

Comment: Works for 1st set of operand, `var result` takes 4digits+1 (for 2nd operand) entered which makes its length 5 and alert pops up. Ideally, `result` should be set to null on encountering any operator and then take the length of the next operand and so on.

Comment: okay, for example,  2345*1234. 4 digit before and after operator. is i am thinking right

Comment: Yes, currently for `2345*1` once 1 is entered the alert pops up. What I want is `[1-4 digits operand] [operator] [1-4 digits operand] [operator] [1-4 digits operand]` and so on...

Comment: okay, i understood i am working on it

Comment: if you like it then please up vote it

Comment: Umm works the first time for operands. But surprisingly fails for the next attempts and the length remains the same throughout.

Comment: Upvoted for the assist, though I'd not accept it as an answer. And would let others share their inputs.

Comment: i think my code works fine, look at the image which i added in a code explanation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest splitting the result into operands, then checking the length of each operand. Example code below:

```js
validResult = "1234+5678"
invalidResult = "12345+123"

function testResult(result) {
  console.log(`Testing "${result}"`);  
  
  // Get operands (i.e. find all numeric substrings)
  const operands = result.match(/[0-9]+/g);
  
  console.log(`Operands are ${operands.join(", ")}`); 
  
  // Measure length of operands
  for(const operand of operands) {
    if(operand.length > 4) {
      // Return false if any of the operands are > 4 digits
      console.log(`"${result}" is not valid`);
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(`"${result}" is valid`);
  return true;
}

// Prints true
console.log(testResult(validResult));

// Prints false
console.log(testResult(invalidResult));
```

Comment: I came up with something similar (edited question). Appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Number()` function? It is exactly what it says it is, it takes a string and converts it to a number. Then you can check if it is larger than 9,999.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be parsed/typecasted as a number, as I have a calculate function that perfectly adds all operands (length<4).

Comment: check for the length of the input using `.length`? maybe that might help

Comment: Gives the operand length, for `2222+2` it gives `5` and alerts out.